# Spring Data LDAP Repository finding ldap entry

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-data, spring-ldap

Hello i have problems with LDAP repository, specifically finding ldap entry using uid and password.

I am using OpenLDAP

See source below

**LdapServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class LdapServiceImpl implements LdapService{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LdapServiceImpl.class); 

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        boolean ret = false;
        try {
            logger.info("{} | {}", username, password);
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] md5password = md.digest(password.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2*md5password.length);
           for(byte b : md5password){
               sb.append(String.format("%02x", b&0xff));
           }

            logger.info("MD5 {}",sb.toString());
            User user = repository.findByUidAndPassword(username, sb.toString());
            if (user != null) {
                ret = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new LdapServiceException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
        } 
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(repository.findAll()); 

    }

}
```

**Users.java (model)**

```
@Data
@Entry(
        base = "ou=Users",
        objectClasses = { "posixAccount", "inetOrgPerson", "top" }
)
public class User {

    @Id
    private Name id;

    @Attribute(name = "uid")
    private String uid;

    @Attribute(name = "cn")
    private String cn;

    @Attribute(name = "sn")
    private String sn;

    @Attribute(name = "givenName")
    private String givenName;

    @Attribute(name = "uidNumber")
    private long uidNumber;

    @Attribute(name = "gidNumber")
    private long gidNumber;

    @Attribute(name = "userPassword")
    private byte[] password;

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return new String(this.password);
    }

}
```

**UserRespository.java**

```
public interface UserRepository extends LdapRepository<User>{

    User findByUid(String username);
    User findByUidAndPassword(String username, String password);
}
```

So basically, when call `findByUid` it returns an entry however, when i try to call `findByUidAndPassword` it is null.

See `LdapServiceImpl.authenticate()` on how it was called.

I read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536341/spring-ldap-how-to-manage-encoded-sha-password) with regards to the password value being read from ldap that is encrypted. However, i have trouble understanding when im trying to find an entry using `uid` and `userPassword`.

This is the log i get when i try to execute LdapServiceImpl.java

```
2019-07-28 20:05:53.983  INFO 10704 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] santa.web.ldap.impl.LdapServiceImpl      : jdoe | jdoe123
2019-07-28 20:05:53.984  INFO 10704 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] santa.web.ldap.impl.LdapServiceImpl      : MD5 9c86d448e84d4ba23eb089e0b5160207
```

When i try to display return of `findByUid` or `findAll` below will be displayed

```
2019-07-28 20:05:53.982  INFO 10704 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.web.services.rests.LoginController     : [User(id=cn=JohnDoe,ou=Users, uid=jdoe, cn=JohnDoe, sn=Doe, givenName=John, uidNumber=2000, gidNumber=100, password={MD5}nIbUSOhNS6I+sIngtRYCBw==)]
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to the part why it can't find the entry on ldap?. because im not sure when to encrypt or not encrypt the string password from user (rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Apparently i am using an incorrect way to encode the string password.

On the OpenLDAP configuration, password was set to MD5.

Base on this guide [Generating password for userPassword](https://angryelectron.com/ldap-md5-java/). It shows that i have to use Base64 class to encode it to md5.

See below snippint on `LdapServiceImpl.java`

```
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
messageDigest.update(password.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF8")));
byte[] digiest = messageDigest.digest();
String hashedOutput = "{MD5}"+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digiest);
logger.info("MD5 {}",hashedOutput);
```

Also i corrected the user model for ldaprepository. it seems that i have converted it wrongly.

```
@Attribute(name = "userPassword")
private byte[] password;

public String getPassword() {
    return new String(this.password);
}
```

I have removed the `setPassword` part since it was incorrectly converting  to byte[]

Hope this helps