# Authenticating LDAP via LDAP Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data, spring-security-ldap

I have trouble resolving different encoding types from my LDAP server (which is in SSHA) and the authenticating value of just plain text.

I am using LDAP Repository to retrieve my LDAP server and used `AuthenticationManager` and my own implementation of `UserDetailService.

The problem is always receive a Bad Credentials exception when i try to authenticate.

As seen on my codes below;

when i request to `/auth`, i have a plain text `username` and `password`. However, i when try to authenticate it via `AuthenticationManager`, it gives me a Bad Credentials. Now, i know that this has got to do with the `UserDetailService.getPassword()` and the `password` i provided in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`. Its about the different encryption type. My LDAP has an {SSHA}, also translated to a binary (bytes) and the encoder is Bcrypt and String.

Now my question is how do you properly **authenticate a password** against the **password return by LdapRespository**?

**UPDATES**

```
2020-04-12 17:09:46.655  INFO 6672 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.SantaRestApiSecurityConfiguration  : Raw Password:  jdoe123 | Encoded Password: {SSHA}kMgk3gD4prAa/9m4wsPbuAoGhO7UvH2v6+W0Dg==
2020-04-12 17:09:58.110  INFO 6672 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.SantaRestApiSecurityConfiguration  : Raw Password: {SSHA}kMgk3gD4prAa/9m4wsPbuAoGhO7UvH2v6+W0Dg== matches Encoded Password: {SSHA}k1Pp3NICHbwuxFFdT7zno/iG/NTILZGL = false
```

Above logs is during password matching in `PasswordEncoder`. Based from it. it shows that the **Raw Password** (inputted by user) has a different hash from the **Encoded Password** (from ldap server).

I used `LdapShaPasswordEncoder.encode` to hash user inputted password.

Also, i noticed that everytime i want to authenticate (call http://locahost:xxxx/auth), the user inputted password's hash **changes** everytime. I think this is normal when hashing

**Security Configuration** ***NOTE: I am allowing all REST-API Endpoints for now, i gonna restrict it later***

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SantaRestApiSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter   {

    @Autowired
    AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(authService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/*");
    }

    /*
     * i am not sure about this since my LDAP server has 
     * a SSHA password encrpytion
     * 
     * */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**LoginController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class LoginController {

    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody Map<String, String> credentials) {
        String username = credentials.get("username");
        String password = credentials.get("password");

        authManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));

        return new ResponseEntity<String>("", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**UserDetailService implementation**

```
@Service
public class AuthService implements UserDetailsService {

    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthService.class);

    @Autowired
    UserLdapRepository ldapRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserLdap e = ldapRepo.findByUid(username);
        logger.info("{}",e.toString());

        return new AuthDetails(e.getCn(), 
                               e.getPassword(),
                               e.getUid(), 
                               e.getMail(), 
                               e.getSn(), 
                               Long.toString( e.getUidNumber()));
    }
}
```

**UserDetails implemenation**

```
public class AuthDetails implements UserDetails {

    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthDetails.class);

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String uidNumber;
    private String sn;
    private String uid;

    public AuthDetails(String username, String password, String uid, String email,String sn, String uidNumber) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.sn = sn;
        this.uidNumber = uidNumber;
    }

    /*
     * Here i am not sure how to implement this one to satisfy AuthenticationManager
     *
     *
     **/
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.username;
    }

    // some method to implement

}
```

Comment: Are you storing the LDAP user password in  BCrypt endcoing?

Comment: no i am only reading an existing LDAP server. No writing or modifying existing data. Right now, the LDAP server i am reading is in SSHA encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You are using BCryptPasswordEncoder but in LDAP is using the SSHA encryption.

You need to modify the method `passwordEncoder` in class `SantaRestApiSecurityConfiguration`

```
  @Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
   return  new LdapShaPasswordEncoder();

}



public Class UserLdap {

    @Attribute(name = "userPassword", type = Type.BINARY)
    private byte[] password;
}
```

and change the method loadUserByUsername

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserLdap e = ldapRepo.findByUid(username);
        logger.info("{}",e.toString());
        String password = "{SSHA}" + new String(e.getPassword());
        return new AuthDetails(e.getCn(), 
                               password,
                               e.getUid(), 
                               e.getMail(), 
                               e.getSn(), 
                               Long.toString( e.getUidNumber()));
    }
```

Comment: Which `LdapShaPasswordEncoder` do i use?, it says here it is deprecated also `encodePassword` does not exist and also `isPasswordValid`. i used`encode` and `matches` respectively as an alternative

Comment: How about password retrieval from ldaprepository. i've read that the value in ldap server for the userPassword i stored binary. How should i convert it?

Comment: I did something similar to this. My problem is that the value i retrive from password field in ldap server is something like `112,12,3,2,21` basically its binarry, then the one i am using to authenticate is a readable string.

Comment: Maybe a problem in UserLdapRepository. it is not getting the password correctly from the LDAP server.

Comment: Nope, returns correctly, its jsut that LDAP servers store password in a binary format. see this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536341/spring-ldap-how-to-manage-encoded-sha-password

Comment: then change date type of  password to byte array in UserLdap and convert into string

Comment: then i cannot get the actual hash from the byte. since its SSHA i can't decrypt it. i think it is a one way thing. Also, SSHA hash generates different hash with the same string password

Comment: I made changes in loadUserByUsername.

Comment: yep did the same, stil cant properly do a match since user inputted password hash is not the same ldap (although plain text is actually the same). See udpates

Comment: apply the base64 on byte array and then try

Comment: actually `new String(e.getPassword());` this line already procudes `{SSHA}...`. the problem is the input from user has a different hash (using the same plain text password)

Comment: Maybe LDAP server storing user password in different encryption.

Comment: actually i checked my ldif defitnion on my server and the one i got on spring logs, both are the same. the problem is the one being hashed from user input